# Content height is reduced with a smaller <div>

Tags: html, css, height, visibility

I have created a dropdown menu. The basic process has been:

- I put the dropdown link and submenus inside a div.
- Using flexbox I put all the links inline and the submenus in a column.
- With the visibility property I make the submenus appear.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main_container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: solid 2px green;
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
}

div {
  width: 110px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 40px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

a {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

div a {
  width: 110px;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: blue;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

div:hover .hidden {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main_container">
  <a href="" class="normal">Enlace1</a>
  <a href="" class="normal">Enlace2</a>
  <div>
    <a href="" class="desplegable">Enlace 3</a>
    <a href="" class="hidden">Enlace 3.1</a>
    <a href="" class="hidden">Enlace 3.2</a>
    <a href="" class="hidden">Enlace 3.3</a>
  </div>
  <a href="" class="normal">Enlace 4</a>
</nav>
```

The key is to reduce the height of the div to 40px, because if you don't, hovering under "Link 3" will still cause the submenu to appear in a weird effect.

Well, when the div is reduced, in height, a value less than the height of the "Link 3" and submenus, curiously the height of these is reduced by 2px as you can see at the bottom of "Link 3".

Can this be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
Changing your `.hidden` class to use the `display` property instead of `visiblity` is also a good idea here. `visibility` still allows the element to render and take up space on the page, which is why it can still be hovered why not visible. However, using `display: none;` makes it so the element does not render and cannot take up space on the page or be hovered.

Typically if you want to show/hide elements on a page you should use `display: none;`. `visibility` can have its uses, typically if you want there to an empty space/void where an element should be. Most of the time you actually want to use `display` instead.

Additionally, I added a `:hover` action to the `div` CSS so that it sets the `height` property to auto only when hovered. This avoids any unusual hover effects from the `<div>` taking up more space.

```css
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

.main_container{
width:500px;
margin:20px auto;
border:solid 2px green;
display:flex;
height:400px;
}

div{
width:110px; 
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
  height: 40px;
}

a{text-decoration:none;
color:white;
width:90px;
text-align:center;
padding:10px;
height:40px;
background-color:red;
}

a{flex-grow:1;}

div a{ 
width:110px;
flex-grow:0;
}

a:hover{
  font-weight: bold;
  background:blue;
} 

.hidden{
  display: none;
}

div:hover .hidden{
  display: inline;
}
div:hover { height: auto; }
```

```html
<nav class="main_container">
  <a href="" class="normal">Enlace1</a>
  <a href="" class="normal">Enlace2</a>

  <div>
    <a href="" class="desplegable">Enlace 3</a>
    <a href="" class="hidden">Enlace 3.1</a>
    <a href="" class="hidden">Enlace 3.2</a>
    <a href="" class="hidden">Enlace 3.3</a>
  </div>

  <a href="" class="normal">Enlace 4</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Sorry EssXTee, i can't remove the height of div because it is important. You can read my post again: "The key is to reduce the height of the div to 40px, because if you don't, hovering under "Link 3" will still cause the submenu to appear in a weird effect."

Comment: @user19503612 I have made an update to my code snippet. Instead of using `visibility` you should use `display` which will actually remove the element. `visibility` allows the element to render and still take up space but is simply not visible.

Comment: It is a good option to use "display" but it isn't correcting the problem with the height of "Enlace 3". When you hover it you can see that the blue height in "Enlace 3" is less than for "Enlace 1, 2 and 4"

Comment: @user19503612 Check my snippet again. I had to add a `:hover` to the `div` CSS to set the height to auto. This fixes that issue.

Comment: Thanks very much EssXTee. It is a useful solution, the links reduce their height because the height of the div is smaller than its content (40px). With the div:hover you delete that situation and the links respond to their height.

Answer (score 0):

inside your css do this to your `a` element:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    width: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    min-height: 40px;
    max-height: 40px;
}
```

add a min-height and max-height and set it to 40px

Comment: Thanks RandomCoder. A simple solution that I had not found

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. You need to use `div {height:100%;}`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main_container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: solid 2px green;
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
}

div {
  width: 110px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

a {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

div a {
  width: 110px;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: blue;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

div:hover .hidden {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main_container">
  <a href="" class="normal">Enlace1</a>
  <a href="" class="normal">Enlace2</a>
  <div>
    <a href="" class="desplegable">Enlace 3</a>
    <a href="" class="hidden">Enlace 3.1</a>
    <a href="" class="hidden">Enlace 3.2</a>
    <a href="" class="hidden">Enlace 3.3</a>
  </div>
  <a href="" class="normal">Enlace 4</a>
</nav>
```